# Javascript function not defined onclick

Tags: html, function, onclick

```js
<head>
 <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  function insertTemplate() {
   console.log('something is coming out');

   if (document.getElementById('template').checked) {
    var test = "lore ipsum";
    document.getElementById('message') = test;
    alert(test);
   }
   else (
    var nothing = '';
    document.getElementById('message') = nothing;
   )
  }
 </script>
</head>
```

```html
<body>
 <form  class='form-horizontal' role='form' method='post'>
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type='text' name='address'><br>
  <input type='text' name='subject'><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='template' id='template' onclick = "insertTemplate()"> Insert in template</br>
  <input type='text' name='message' id = 'message' style='width:500px;height:500px;'><br>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
 </form>
</body>
```

I am creating an application using Laravel. I am trying to populate a text field with text when the user clicks on a checkbox. However, I keep on getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: insertTemplate is not defined" as an error whenever I check the box. I seem to have stated the function on the "onclick" attribute of the input and have defined the function. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: else probably should be written with curly braces

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` block was delimited by parentheses instead of curly braces.

```html
 <form  class='form-horizontal' role='form' method='post'>
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type='text' name='address'><br>
  <input type='text' name='subject'><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='template' id='template' onclick = "insertTemplate()"> Insert in template<br>
  <input type='text' name='message' id = 'message' style='width:500px;height:500px;'><br>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
 </form>
  
   <script>
  function insertTemplate() {
   console.log('something is coming out');
      
      var test = "lore ipsum"
      var nothing = "";

   if (document.getElementById('template').checked) {
    document.getElementById('message').textContent = test;
    alert(test);
   } else {
    document.getElementById('message').textContent = nothing;
   }
  }
 </script>
```